# SQL Server CE nested SELECT in FROM clause

Tags: sql-server, razor, sql-server-ce

I am trying to run the following query in SQL Server CE and it won't run. On the other hand, when I run it in SQL Server I get the query successfully.

```
SELECT N 
FROM
     (SELECT CONVERT(int,LN) AS N 
      FROM
          (SELECT SUBSTRING([Pt_ID],1,1) AS L, SUBSTRING([Pt_ID],2,3) AS LN
           FROM [ControlPointName]
           WHERE [Pt_ID] LIKE 'A___') CTE1) CTE2
WHERE   
    N = 456
```

This is what my dataset looks like:

```
Pt_ID
A453
A454
A455
A456
```

What the query is doing is extracting the numerical digits from the column, so then the number `456` can be used.

The error I get is the following:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 39, Token in error = ( ]

What do I need to change in order to make it work in SQL Server CE? or what would be a different way of doing it? Thank you.

Comment: Sql ce does not support udfs and does not support nested select in from clause

Comment: Thanks, and what would be a way around it (nested SELECT)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING([Pt_ID],2,3) AS int) AS N
   FROM [ControlPointName]
    WHERE [Pt_ID] LIKE 'A456%'
```

Comment: I should have specified that I need to have N =456 as an int since I'm going to use the number to do some math. I will update my question.

Comment: By the way, thank you very much for SQL CE Toolbox. It has been very very useful!

Comment: Feel free to post a review on Vs Gallery, if you like!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked well:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int,LN) FROM(
    SELECT  SUBSTRING([Pt_ID],1,1) AS L,
            SUBSTRING([Pt_ID],2,3) AS LN
    FROM    [ControlPointName]
    WHERE   [Pt_ID] LIKE 'A___'
) CTE
WHERE LN = 456
```